# delete folder that contains WAR files

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder in E drive which contains few .WAR file.

i have wriiten a batch script as follow to delete the folder which contains .WAR files .

```
    @echo off

    rmdir /s /q "path to my folder"
```

the code doesn't delete the folder.

can anyone help me?.

Comment: Turn `echo` on and put a `pause` at the end, or just run it from a cmd prompt, then you will see the error and why it won't delete.

Answer (score 2):

If the error message you get is, "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." then your default directory is probably equal to "path to my folder".  Add the following line to your batch script before the "rmdir" line: "cd \"  This will ensure your default directory is not the directory you are trying to delete.